# How to extract values from text fields in RCP and place it in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse-rcp

I am creating a RCP application which takes source and destination from text fields and gives directions using Google Maps API in a different view. I have javascript code which calls the API, but I need source and destination to be taken from my RCP text fields instead of specifying in the HTML file. How to extract values from those fields and place in the javascript code?

If anyone can share their idea, I would appreciate.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you are stuck in this.. but hope this helps

```
Text sourceText = new Text(...);
Text destinationText = new Text(...);

//To get value from this text 

String source = sourceText.getText();
String destination = destinationText .getText();
```

But question seems so trivial, that i doubt this is what you want..

Comment: Thank you, and sorry that I cannot upvote your answer since I don't have the required reputation.

Comment: Can you please upvote my question and enable me to post questions again? I am currently blocked due to some criteria of Stackoverflow.